# Как эффективно реализовать свой BigInteger?

Tags: алгоритм, динамические-массивы, типы-данных, динамические-структуры

Захотелось реализовать свой BigInteger, но хочется сделать его максимально эффективным и быстрым. В первую очередь меня интересует как эффективно реализовать представление числа. Несомненно первая идея - представлять каждую цифру в 10-ричной системе счисления в отдельном массиве или строке. Но я [не](https://stackoverflow.com/a/269291/12332444) раз [видел](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269268/how-to-implement-big-int-in-c#comment5584804_269268) советы о том, что представление чисел в 2^n-ричной системе счисления является наиболее лучшим решением. Вопрос почему? Как реализовывать в такой системе счисления побитовые сдвиги? Как будут вообще работать все операции? Умножение? Деление? Также [Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1153008/280035) упомянул 10^9-ричную систему счисления (в конце свеого ответа). Почему это также будет лучшим решением, чем просто десятиричная? Меньше создавать "блоков" для каждого числа? И из этого большая скорость работы?

1. Как лучше представлять числа?
2. Как лучше их хранить? строкой? динамическим массивом?
3. Как реализовывать операции в таких "представлениях"?

Comment: тут всё есть ...........................https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Длинная_арифметика

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте просто прикинем, сколько операций сложения нужно, чтобы сложить два, скажем, 99-значных числа вашим способом. Минимально - 99 сложений + 99 сложений с переносом + 99 делений и получений остатка. У вас еще и преобразований в символы...

Если работать с ограничением в миллиард - уже в 9 раз меньше.

Рассмотрим умножение - тут получаются числа порядка n*n, т.е. здесь применение миллиарда вместо символа ускорит операции как минимум в 81 раз :)

Ну, а почему 2<sup>*n*</sup> - да просто чтоб использовать память экономнее. Полный диапазон. Да и сами операции зачастую выполняются быстрее - особенно с остатком и делением - можно просто битовыми операциями.

Проблема только в том, что умножение и сложение пишутся очень просто, а вот деление... А без деления как выводить в десятеричном виде?

Вот потому я и упомянул миллиард - если деление не нужно (а в олимпиадных задачах это распространенное явление), а в каждом элементе - 9 разрядов длинного числа - то его очень легко вывести: просто выводить как есть, разве что добивая нулями слева при необходимости каждый разряд...

Вот, посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1151180/195342) - это одна из таких задачек, где нужно только суммировать/умножать. Интереса ради замените

```
static const unsigned int magic = 1000000000, digs = 9;
```

на

```
static const unsigned int magic = 100, digs = 2;
```

и сравните время работы для реально больших чисел...